# C# Simple Regex - 32 characters, containing only 0-9 and a-f (GUID)

Tags: c#, regex, guid

How to test using regex in C# if:

- length of string is exactly 32
- string contains only numbers from 0-9 and small letters from a-f

Comment: What have you tried? How has that worked out for you? What kinds of things didn't work? We're here to help. Not to do the work.

Comment: I know how to check length OR check 0-9 OR a-f but I can't combine that all :(

Comment: It would still be useful if you posted the things you've tried

Comment: Are you sure the string is not actually a Guid?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9a-f]{32}$");
if (regex.IsMatch(text))
...
```

Comment: I think you're missing the hyphen out.

Comment: @SimonOliverHurley: Not from the description in the question. "string contains only numbers from 0-9 and small letters from a-f" - no mention of a hyphen in there.

Answer (score 10):

In .Net 4.0 there is `Guid` structure that has `TryParse` static function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you're not dead-set on using a Regex for this purpose, this is pretty clean:

```
Func<char, bool> charValid = c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f');
bool isValid = text.Length == 32 && text.All(charValid);
```

Comment: I prefer the regex a million times. It’s shorter, cleaner, easier to understand and to change, probably even more efficient (not that I checked, or that it matters). – Why are some people so keen to avoid them?

Comment: @Konrad me personally because they usually are very bad at communicating intend and generally perform worse than more readable options. In this particular case I don't mind the simple one need though calling a method on Guid would be my preferred option if at all possible

Comment: @Konrad, I like Regex, particularly for more sophisticated tasks that require complex contextual matching.  If the problem is relatively simple, however, I often prefer a more explicit approach, if only because not all of my colleagues have a good working understanding of Regex.

Comment: @Dan: your last sentence is a logical fallacy. If your colleagues don’t know regex, they should take an afternoon or two and learn it. You cannot just avoid it because some people may not know it (yet). By the same reasoning, you can (and should!) essentially forbid any programming technique that surpasses the most basic level of understanding. Avoiding a technique because of others’ ignorance is bad. It requires better reasons to shun such techniques. This is a sentiment I encounter quite often (not only with regex) and I oppose it, **strongly**. It leads to objectively worse code.

Comment: @Rune: most people drastically underestimate the performance of regular expressions. Regular expression automata can be traversed *extraordinarily* fast. In fact, matching regular expressions are often *much faster* than all other obvious solutions. If only because the guys building the library know much more about string matching than your average Joe. – The only slow thing about regular expressions is *building* them. And where it matters, this can be mitigated by compiling/caching the expression. Furthermore, even that step performs much better than most people think.

Comment: @Konrad, my experience has been that the trade-off between complexity of implementation and use of higher level techniques is rarely so clear-cut.  If my colleagues are not familiar with the techniques and I make use of them, I am contributing to project risk and I need to weigh this against the benefits.  In many cases, the benefits are worth the added risk, such as if the technique is significantly easier to implement or more expressive of intent.  I'm quite happy to use Mocking for this reason.  It's harder to make a case when the task is already so simple in a 'mainstream' form.

Comment: @Konrad I can only speak for my self and I'm not guessing. I've yet to stumble into a solution where, when meassured, a regex solution (in .NET) was faster than a non regex for the same problem. Add to that the testability, readability and maintainability problems often encure with regex and that to me makes it the answer to your original question obvious

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so there's an answer here that shows you how to find out if this string is 32 characters in length, and each character is either a digit or lowercase 'a' to lowercase 'f' with a regex, and another that shows you how to do it with a simple Func which scans that characters in the string.  They're both great answers and technically correct, but in your question title you explicitly state "GUID" which opens up a new can of worms.

GUIDs can take a number of different string representations, and you might encounter any one of them.  Do you need to handle all of these?  Will you need to accomodate strings that begin and end with curly braces ('{' and '}') or parentheses?  What about dashes ('-')?  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx), creating a new GUID with

```
string s = ...;
Guid g = new Guid(s);
```

Allows for strings in the following forms

> 32 contiguous digits: 
>   dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
>
> -or-
>
> Groups of 8, 4, 4, 4, and 12 digits
>   with hyphens between the groups. The
>   entire GUID can optionally be enclosed
>   in matching braces or parentheses: 
>   dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd
>
> -or-
>
> {dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd}
>
> -or-
>
> (dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd)
>
> -or-
>
> Groups of 8, 4, and 4 digits, and
>   a subset of eight groups of 2 digits,
>   with each group prefixed by "0x" or
>   "0X", and separated by commas. The
>   entire GUID, as well as the subset, is
>   enclosed in matching braces:  {0xdddddddd, 0xdddd, 0xdddd,{0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd}}

Do you need to handle all of these cases?  Also, consider if using a regex is *really* the best option.  As some people have already commented, regex can be confusing for some developers, and the intent isn't always clear.  On top of that, regex can be *slow* in some cases.

I whipped up a quick performance test on three different ways of determining if a string is in fact a string representation of a GUID:

1. Regex
2. Checking all chars in the string
3. Creating a new Guid instance with the given string (if the Guid can be created, then the string is a valid string representation)

Here's the code:

[Test]

```
public void Test_IsRegex_Performance()
{
    Action withRegexMatch = () =>
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9a-f]{32}$");
        Guid g = new Guid();
        string s = g.ToString();
        regex.IsMatch(s);
    };

    Action withCharCheck = () =>
    {
        Guid g = new Guid();
        string s = g.ToString();

        Func<char, bool> charValid = c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f');
        bool isValid = s.Length == 32 && s.All(charValid);
    };

    Action withNewGuid = () =>
    {
        Guid g = new Guid();
        string s = g.ToString();
        try
        {
            Guid g2 = new Guid(s);
            // if no exception is thrown, this is a valid string 
            // representation
        }
        catch
        {
            // if an exception was thrown, this is an invalid
            // string representation
        }
    };

    const int times = 100000;

    Console.WriteLine("Regex: {0}", TimedTask(withRegexMatch, times));
    Console.WriteLine("Checking chars: {0}", TimedTask(withCharCheck, times));
    Console.WriteLine("New Guid: {0}", TimedTask(withNewGuid, times));
    Assert.Fail();
}

private static TimeSpan TimedTask(Action action, int times)
{
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        action();
    }
    timer.Stop();
    return timer.Elapsed;
}
```

And the results from a million iterations on my machine:

```
Regex: 00:00:10.1786901
Checking chars: 00:00:00.2504520
New Guid: 00:00:01.3129005
```

So, the regex solution is slow.  Ask yourself if you *really* need a regex here.  Note that you can probably eek out some extra performance by only declaring the regex once, and reusing it, but I think the point in this case is that you might have better success by looking at *what* you're trying to accomplish, as opposed to *how*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The benchmark is totally unfair and unrepresentative. At the very least, build the expression once and reuse it. Furthermore, also try a *compiled* regular expression solution. This may not matter much for this particular expression but then again, it may. Same goes for `new Guid`. Remove the `try` block and use `Guid.TryParse` instead.

Comment: A few points: What I was driving at with my post was that Guids can take a number of different forms, so perhaps the posters code needs to handle that.  I did address the fact that the Regex can be declared once and reused.  Also, Guid.TryParse only exists in .net 4.0, so I didn't try that - I would wager that the performance would be somewhat similar to creating a new Guid instance (probably a bit faster).

Comment: Finally, the point about Regex being difficult for many developers still stands, I think.  The intent isn't always clear, and unless there is a very specific reason to use them (for example, checking if the text is all numeric, or is a well-formed phone number), I rarely touch them.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @mjd: the point about GUIDs is that your code requires catching an exception which is *bound* to be slow. `TryParse` doesn’t incur that overhead. About regex, you mentioned it, but you didn’t measure it. Read my comment again: “your *benchmark* is … unrepresentative”. And whether or not the regex is difficult for many developers is another question entirely, and irrelevant besides (read my comment below Dan’s answer).

Comment: @Konrad Guid.TryParse uses a try/catch block internally to test if the string is parseable.  I just tested it, and the time is around the same as using the try/catch.  I admit that the regex solution might be preferable in some cases, but this might not be one of them - the regex given doesn't handle a whole host of possible valid cases, and even if you modified it to handle those cases, you'd basically be duplicating the functionality in TryParse.  The point of my post was that instead of saying, "how do I solve this with a regex," it's probably better to say, "how do I solve this."  Cheers.

Comment: @mjd: I agree that `Guid.TryParse` (and perhaps even the `try…catch` solution) is preferable to a regular expression solution – **because it already exists** and is bespoke for this job. If `Guid.TryParse` really uses `try` internally, that kind of sucks, though (but I’d still use it unless performance really were an issue).